# Calcular resultado con registro anterior y actualizar en el nuevo registro

Tags: mysql

Quiero hacer un recorrido por la tabla 'data' y en cada uno de los registros necesito tomar el Mileage del registro anterior, luego restar Nuevo Mileage - Viejo Mileage y dividirlo entre Liters para sacar Efficiency y asignarselo al registro , pero no se mucho de base de datos, como podría leer cada registro y actualizar?

de antemano muchas gracias! les dejo captura.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta esto:

Para recorrer la tabla **data** y obtener el **Mileage** viejo y restarlo con el nuevo y tambien con la división de dicha resta:

```
SELECT mileage,
       mileage_previo,
       (mileage - mileage_previo) as resta,
       (mileage - mileage_previo) / liters  as efficiency 
FROM(
    SELECT mileage,
           CASE
            WHEN (SELECT d2.id FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id < d.id LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE (SELECT d2.id FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id < d.id LIMIT 1) 
           END mileage_previo,
           liters 
    FROM data d
) t
```

Ahora para insertar en la tabla **data** en base a este **query** solo tienes que hacer:

```
 INSERT INTO data (mileage, liters , ..., coln)
 SELECT mileage,
           mileage_previo,
           (mileage - mileage_previo) as resta,
           (mileage - mileage_previo) / liters  as efficiency 
    FROM(
        SELECT mileage,
               CASE
                WHEN (SELECT d2.id FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id < d.id LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE (SELECT d2.id FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id < d.id LIMIT 1) 
               END mileage_previo,
               liters 
        FROM data d
    ) t
```

ó actualizar que creo que es lo que tu quieres:

```
UPDATE data
SET efficiency = (SELECT 
                   (mileage - mileage_previo) / liters  as efficiency 
                  FROM(
                     SELECT mileage,
                            CASE
                              WHEN (SELECT d2.id FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id < d.id LIMIT 1) IS NULL THEN 0
                              ELSE (SELECT d2.id FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id < d.id LIMIT 1) 
                              END mileage_previo,
                           liters 
                     FROM data d
                    ) t
                  )
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM data)
```

Comment: muy completa respuesta + 1

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano!

Comment: Entiendo mas o menos lo que haces hermano pero no me respeta el mileage anterior, solo tuve que cambiar aqui: ELSE (SELECT (**d2.id**)  d2.mileage FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id < d.id LIMIT 1)

Comment: te sirvio de algo?

Comment: Si hermano, muchísimo enserio te lo agradezco!, ahora lo tratare de modificar, es que tengo sucursales y esas mismas tienen rutas (asset_id), quiero ordenarla por asset_id y fecha (intake) e iterar en cada uno para hacerlo, estaba pensando tal vez en un while,que opinas tu hermano?

Comment: Que bueno, si me puedes colocar mi respuesta como correcta te lo agradeceria gracias y suerte

Comment: Listo hermano! saludos!

Comment: Gracias, pero eso que hicistes fue darme un voto muchas gracias por eso yo te decia abajo donde votas existe una especie de **visto bueno** o **✓**, con eso marcas la respuesta como correcta, muchas gracias

Comment: Ahora si listo hermano! gracias a ti!